# Getting DOM attributes with GWT OnFirstAttach handler ignores CSS

Tags: gwt

I would like to add a Title to a GWT Label when the Label's offset width is greater than its parent's offset (DOM Values). However, when I debug at Super Dev Mode, I see that those two offsets are equal since CSS style is ignored until all attach events are completed. My workaround to this issue is adding a MouseOverHandler and doing the calculation during this event. Is there a type of attach handler where it considers the CSS manipulated DOM too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule your title assignment logic for the next iteration of JS event loop by using [Scheduler#scheduleDeferred()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred(com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand)), i.e.:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
   @Override
   public void execute() {
     // CSS values have been applied - decide on title assignment.
   }
});
```